# ClickUp webhook

Tags: python, webhooks

I am trying to configure Webhooks on clickup but I couldn't find it on the settings section. Is it not available on ClickUp's free plan?

I tried to check the settings for integration but there is none, or it redirects me to apps. How can I use webhooks and where can I put the endpoint for the webhook?

```
ngrok_url = 'https://abcdefg.ngrok.io'

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    
    webhook_data = request.json
    print("Webhook Data:", webhook_data)

    
    if event_type in ['taskCreated', 'taskUpdated', 'taskDeleted']:
        update_database(task_id, task_name, event_type)

    return jsonify({'message': 'Webhook received successfully'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhooks are a ClickUp automation. You can trigger them based on an event in ClickUp.

1. Go to automations in the top right
2. Pick your trigger
3. Put Webhook as the action
4. Add your URL

[I also wrote an article about ClickUp API](https://www.upsys-consulting.com/en/blog-en/how-to-make-use-of-the-clickup-api-features-examples) to get you started